# Getting an error with Numpy where condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am trying create a new column with using `np.where` condition of other columns in the database.

**My code**

```
  df5['RiskSubType']=np.where(new_df['Snow_Risk']==1,(( ' Heavy Snow forecasted at  ' +df5.LOCATION.mask(new_df.LOCATION=='',df5.LOCATION_CITY))),
np.where(df5['Wind_Risk']==1,( ' Heavy Wind forecasted at  ' +df5.LOCATION.mask(df5.LOCATION=='',df5.LOCATION_CITY)),
np.where(df5['Precip_Risk']==1,( ' Heavy Rain forecasted at  ' +df5.LOCATION.mask(df5.LOCATION=='',df5.LOCATION_CITY)),"No Risk Identified")))
```

Error

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes
```

How to fix this or this alternative way do this.

Comment: SO if I break it down into simpler syntax your code is: `df5['RST'] = np.where(new_df['SR'] == 1, 'a', np.where(df5['WR']==1, 'b', np.where(df['PR']==1, 'c', 'd')))` right? just to make it a bit more readable.

Comment: @LeoE,Its correct

Comment: Please provide a minimum data frame, say four rows.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you done any research? What do you understand from that error message? Also, is the error message cut off? It looks like it should give the shapes involved. I will say nothing of the seemingly awful design/code style.

Comment: is that the full error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first of all, your design/code style is really hard to read, you should think about simplifying it.
Your problems occurs due to the fact, that you are trying to smash strings and arrays in the `np.where` function. The [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) says:

> numpy.where(condition[, x, y])
>
> Return elements chosen from x or y depending on condition.
>
> Parameters:
>
> condition : array_like, bool
>
> > Where True, yield x, otherwise yield y.
> >     x, y : array_like
> >     Values from which to choose. x, y and condition need to be broadcastable to some shape.
>
> Returns:
>
> out : ndarray
>
> > An array with elements from x where condition is True, and elements from y elsewhere.

As you can see **x and y need to be broadcastable to some shape**. Looking at the [documentation of broadcastable](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html):

> 6.4. Broadcasting
>
> Another powerful feature of Numpy is broadcasting. Broadcasting takes
>   place when you perform operations between arrays of different shapes.
>   For instance
>
> ```
> >>> a = np.array([
>     [0, 1],
>     [2, 3],
>     [4, 5],
>     ])
> >>> b = np.array([10, 100])
> >>> a * b
> array([[  0, 100],
>        [ 20, 300],
>        [ 40, 500]])
> ```
>
> The shapes of a and b don’t match. In order to proceed, Numpy will
>   stretch b into a second dimension, as if it were stacked three times
>   upon itself. The operation then takes place element-wise.
>
> One of the rules of broadcasting is that only dimensions of size 1 can
>   be stretched (if an array only has one dimension, all other dimensions
>   are considered for broadcasting purposes to have size 1). In the
>   example above b is 1D, and has shape (2,). For broadcasting with a,
>   which has two dimensions, Numpy adds another dimension of size 1 to b.
>   b now has shape (1, 2). This new dimension can now be stretched three
>   times so that b’s shape matches a’s shape of (3, 2).
>
> The other rule is that dimensions are compared from the last to the
>   first. Any dimensions that do not match must be stretched to become
>   equally sized. However, according to the previous rule, only
>   dimensions of size 1 can stretch. This means that some shapes cannot
>   broadcast and Numpy will give you an error:
>
> ```
> >>> c = np.array([
>     [0, 1, 2],
>     [3, 4, 5],
>     ])
> >>> b = np.array([10, 100])
> >>> c * b
> ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,3) (2,)
> ```
>
> What happens here is that Numpy, again, adds a dimension to b, making
>   it of shape (1, 2). The sizes of the last dimensions of b and c (2 and
>   3, respectively) are then compared and found to differ. Since none of
>   these dimensions is of size 1 (therefore, unstretchable) Numpy gives
>   up and produces an error.
>
> The solution to multiplying c and b above is to specifically tell
>   Numpy that it must add that extra dimension as the second dimension of
>   b. This is done by using None to index that second dimension. The
>   shape of b then becomes (2, 1), which is compatible for broadcasting
>   with c:
>
> ```
> >>> c = np.array([
>     [0, 1, 2],
>     [3, 4, 5],
>     ])
> >>> b = np.array([10, 100])
> >>> c * b[:, None]
> array([[  0,  10,  20],
>        [300, 400, 500]])
> ```
>
> A good visual description of these rules, together with some advanced
>   broadcasting applications can be found in this tutorial of Numpy broadcasting rules.

So the problem is, that you are trying to broadcast an `(n,)`(first where) to a `scalar`(first string) to a `(m,)`(second where) to a `scalar`(second string) to a `(k,)`(third where) and so on. Since `n != m != k` can and will be the case and the dimensions for stretching do not match the broadcasting does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Please provide something like this:

```
d = {'LOCATION': ['?', '?'],
     'LOCATION_CITY': ['?', '?'],
     'Wind_Risk': [1, 0],
     'Precip_Risk': [1, 0],
     'Snow_Risk': [1, 0]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```